# How to call my parallel Quicksort function?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, quicksort

I get a compilation error when trying to call the following `QuicksortParallel` method from `Main`. It is not clear to me what parameters to pass to get rid of the error. My aim is to sort an array and finally print it.

```
public static void QuicksortParallel<T>(List<T> arr, int left, int right)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    const int Threshold = 2048;
    if (right <= left)
        return;

    if (right - left < Threshold)
        Quicksort(arr, left, right);
    else
    {
        var pivot = Partition(arr, left, right);

        // Sorting the left and right of the pivot in parallel.
        Parallel.Invoke(
            () => QuicksortParallel(arr, left, pivot - 1),
            () => QuicksortParallel(arr, pivot + 1, right)
            );
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] unsorted = { "z", "e", "x", "c", "m", "q", "a" };

    // Print the unsorted array.
    for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.Length; i++)
        Console.Write(unsorted[i] + " ");

    Console.WriteLine();

    // Sort the array.
    QuicksortParallel(unsorted, 0, unsorted.Length - 1); // <-- Error here.

    // Print the sorted array.
    for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.Length; i++)
        Console.Write(unsorted[i] + " ");

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

So, what should I give to function `QuicksortParallel` in `Main` to sort the array?

Comment: Try with this: `QuicksortParallel(unsorted.ToList())`. Remember adding `using System.Linq;` at the top of your source file. Also, make sure there is a reference to `System.Core` in you project.

Comment: No overload for method ' QuickSortParallel ' takes 1 argument .

Comment: Right. It should be `QuicksortParallel(unsorted.ToList(), 0, unsorted.Length - 1);`. I really think you should learn some C#, thoguh. Is this some kind of a homework?

Comment: yeah it works thanks , but the printed array still unsorted !

Comment: Correct. That would sort a **copy** of the array, as a list. You would have to keep a reference to the copy in another variable, then print that instead.

Comment: Always list the exact error you get. “I get an error” does not say nearly enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] unsorted = { "z", "e", "x", "c", "m", "q", "a" };

    // Print the unsorted array.
    for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.Length; i++)
        Console.Write(unsorted[i] + " ");

    Console.WriteLine();

    // Get a copy of the array, as a list.
    List<string> list = unsorted.ToList();

    // Sort the list.
    QuicksortParallel(list, 0, list.Count - 1);

    // Print the sorted list.
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        Console.Write(list[i] + " ");

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: hahaha , thanks mr. santa , done (Y)